# OGNL dynamic access map with iterator var

Tags: jsp, iterator, ognl

I'm trying to access a map using OGNL, and I can't really access the map using the iterator var, but I can access it using the status.

Basically, this works:

```
<s:iterator value="categories" var="citem" status="stat">
<s:property value='catColors[#stat.count]' />
<s:property value='#citem.id]' />
</s:iterator>
```

This won't work:

```
<s:iterator value="categories" var="citem" status="stat">
<s:property value='catColors[#citem.id]' />
</s:iterator>
```

I can't really find out why. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What is `categories` and its contents?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<s:iterator value="categories" var="citem" status="stat">
<s:property value='catColors[[0].id]' />
</s:iterator>
```

In struts [0] gets the current iterated value on the stack, which in your example would be the same as the "citem".

I am guessing that you are trying to get the catColors[] indexed at "id".